# Ajax post to same page returns data and entire file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want users to fill out a form and have the inputs sent to a PHP script in the SAME file. To clarify: the form, ajax script, and PHP are all in the same file. I realize splitting up the PHP into its own request.php file is best practice, but I really want to get this method to work. I have the following code:

PHP

```
$country = $_POST['ccode'];  
$postal = $_POST['pcode'];
```

Ajax

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#quick-quote').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
           url: "same-page.php",
           method: 'POST',
           data: {
             ccode: $('#country').val(),
             pcode: $('#postal').val()
           },
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
           },
           error: function(data){
             console.log("ajax failure");
           }
         });
       });
      });
```

HTML

```
<form id="quick-quote" class="" action="" method="post">
  <label>Country</label>
  <select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
  </select>
  <label>Postal Code</label>
  <input id="postal" type="text" name="postal" value="">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

When ajax is executed the console prints out:

```
 Array
(
    [ccode] => AU
    [pcode] => 3000
)
```

Followed by the contents of the ENTIRE file (PHP, Jquery, HTML).

I have already tested a separate php file and posted the ajaxed values to it which worked fine. But I really want this all the occur in the same file (if possible). So my question is: how can I parse just the array out of the ajax post? Or better, how can I only post the relevant key value pairs and not the rest of my file. I have seen other posts regarding ajax returning entire files, but not when it is called in the same page.

Comment: You need to structure your PHP code so that it recognises when it's receiving an AJAX request and only returns the array.

Comment: It's much better to have a php scripts, scripts, and template in the separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must you `exit` to terminate further execution. For example:

```
<?php //Place it in the top most of your file.
if(isset($_POST)){
    //perform your operations here
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
...
</html>
```